# Hide buttons on start of Android app

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a `MenuView ViewGroup` which capsules all the buttons of my interface.
On start of the app all buttons are positioned via `button.layout()`. Then I hide all buttons, with one exception: the menu button. When I am pressing the menu button, all other buttons are shown (via a zoom animation).

Now the problem: while positioning the buttons via `button.layout()`, they are visible. So almost 1 sec all buttons are shown on startup of the app.

How can I avoid that?

My button code:

```
public class CircleButton extends Button {

    static final int StateDefault = 0;
    static final int StateFocused = 1;
    static final int StatePressed = 2;


    private Bitmap mBitmapDefault;

    private String mCaption;
    protected int radius;
    protected int color = 0xff000000;
    private Typeface font1;
    private boolean visible = true;
    private int savedLeft, savedTop;
    // indicates whether the button is visible when the menu is rendered
    public boolean visibleInMenu = true;
    private Paint paint;
    private static String TAG = "CircleButton";

    public int getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }


    public CircleButton setRadius(int radius){
        this.radius = radius;
        this.setWidth(2*radius);
        this.setHeight(2*radius);
        return this;
    }

    public CircleButton setColor(int color){
        this.color = color;
        return this;
    }

    public CircleButton setCaption(String caption){
        mCaption = caption;
        return this;
    }
    public CircleButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        setClickable(true);
        setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Bebas/BEBAS___.ttf");
        mCaption = "Caption";
        this.setRadius(45);
        this.setTextSize(18);

        setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    }

    public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        if(visibility == GONE){
            this.visible = false;
        }else{
            this.visible = true;
        }
        super.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
    /**
     * draws the normal button (without rollover)
     * @param canvas
     */
    protected void drawDefault(Canvas canvas){
        //canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        Paint paintText = new Paint();
        paintText.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintText.setTextSize(this.getTextSize());
        paintText.setColor(0xffffffff); // white
        paintText.setTypeface(this.font1);

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        //Paint textPaint = this.getPaint();
        paintText.getTextBounds(mCaption,0,mCaption.length(),bounds);

        float left = (float) (2*radius-bounds.width())/2;
        float top = (float) radius+bounds.height()/2;
        //Log.v("Button","bounds:"+bounds.width()+"x"+bounds.height());
        //Log.v("Button","this.getWIdth:"+2*radius);
        // create the Drawing Tool (Brush)
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true); // for a nicer paint

        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(radius, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        canvas.save(); 
        canvas.rotate(-45,this.getRadius(),this.getRadius());
        canvas.drawText(mCaption, left, top, paintText);
        canvas.restore();
    }



    protected Bitmap getDefaultBitmap(){
        if(mBitmapDefault == null){
            mBitmapDefault = Bitmap.createBitmap(2*radius, 2*radius, Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmapDefault);
            this.drawDefault(canvas);
            return mBitmapDefault;
        }
        return mBitmapDefault;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Log.v("Button","onDraw(): "+this.getWidth()+"x"+this.getHeight());
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.getDefaultBitmap(), 0, 0, paint);
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(this.getDefaultBitmap(), new Rect(0, 0, this.radius*8, this.radius*8), new Rect(0,0, this.radius*2, this.radius*2), null);
    }


    public void recycle() {
        if(mBitmapDefault != null){
            mBitmapDefault.recycle();
            mBitmapDefault = null;
        }
    }

    public void hide(){
        this.hide(true);
    }
    public void hide(boolean withAnimation){
        if(this.visible == true){
            savedLeft = getLeft();
            savedTop = getTop();

            ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 0, 1, 0, this.getRadius(), this.getRadius());
            anim.setDuration(300);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    visible = false;
                    layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            });
            this.startAnimation(anim);

        }

    }

    public void show(){
        if(this.visible == false){
            this.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            OvershootInterpolator inter = new OvershootInterpolator();
            ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, this.getRadius(), this.getRadius());
            anim.setDuration(300);
            anim.setInterpolator(inter);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    visible = true;

                }
            });
            this.startAnimation(anim);

            this.layout(this.savedLeft, this.savedTop, this.savedLeft+2*this.radius, this.savedTop+2*this.radius);
        }
        this.visible = true;
    }


    public CircleButton setOnClickCallback(OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(l);
        return this;
    }
    private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    };

    private OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Log.v("Button","onTouch()");
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                OvershootInterpolator inter = new OvershootInterpolator();
                ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, (float) 1.5, 1,(float) 1.5, CircleButton.this.getRadius(), CircleButton.this.getRadius());
                anim.setInterpolator(inter);
                anim.setDuration(200);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                CircleButton.this.startAnimation(anim);
            }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation((float) 1.5, 1, (float) 1.5, 1, CircleButton.this.getRadius(), CircleButton.this.getRadius());
                anim.setDuration(300);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                CircleButton.this.startAnimation(anim);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You could try changing button visibility on startup in xml instead of the java file.

Comment: I don't use xml. I am using this.addView(button);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [setVisibility(int visibility)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) method on the object to hide it with Parameter visibility  One of VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE:

### GONE

This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.
Constant Value: 8 (0x00000008)

### INVISIBLE

This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.
Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)

### VISIBLE

This view is visible. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.
Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)

Comment: It seems to me that positioning the button via "button.layout()" is only working when the button is visible. calling button.setVisibillity(INVISIBLE) before OR after button.layout() results in a button positioned on the very top left of the screen :(

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `android:visibility="invisible"` to those buttons in your layout xml.

Comment: or `gone` depending on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: sorry, forgot to say: the buttons are added on runtime via this.addView(button);